# BigCommerce PHP API Ciper Error

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am using the BigCommerce PHP API and am receiving this error when it attempts to connect to either my store or the webdav store:

*failed setting cipher list*

From the same server I have connected to both sites using cURL via the command line.  I have the cURL php module installed with SSL enabled.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to enable the 'rsa_rc4_128_sha' cipher. It might not be enabled by default. Can you try

```
Connection::setCipher()
```

before making a request? By default this sets the cipher to the above cipher as default.

There is some history on this in the BC github repos -

https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/10

https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/11

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was using wamp and tested this just now.

To fix this I updated the connection api file with

curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\big\Bigcommerce\Certs\cacert.pem');

and the file from

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Answer (score 0):

We use an object based upon the following

```
<?php
// provision for laziness
if( 
    (array_key_exists('store_url', (array)$settings)) &&
    (array_key_exists('username', $settings)) && 
    (array_key_exists('api_key', $settings)) 
) {
    // Config Basic
    BC::configure(
        array(
            'store_url' => $settings['store_url'],
            'username'  => $settings['username'],
            'api_key'   => $settings['api_key']
        )
    );

    // Set Cipher if needed
    if(array_key_exists('cipher',$settings)) {
        BC::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
    } else {
        BC::verifyPeer(false);
    }

    // Set Proxy if needed
    if(array_key_exists('proxy',$settings)) {
        BC::useProxy($settings['proxy']['url'], $settings['proxy']['port']);
    }
}
// Run your code here...
```